# How to check if a coordinate pair (lat,lon) exists in a coordinate grid?

Tags: python, numpy, logic, geography

I have an algorithm that computes shapes using geographic coordinates when certain conditions are satisfied. The algorithm outputs a latitude list and a longitude list like seen below. So lat[0] and lon[0] would represent a coordinate pair. I want to create a boolean array in the shape of a latitude and longitude map where the indices would be true if a corresponding coordinate point exists in the algorithm output. I have the original latitude and longitude information from the netcdf file, but how do I make a 2d array of coordinate points that can be compared against the algorithm output, and then use the matching indices to make this boolean array?

I've tried combining the latitude and longitude into a single array. `len(lat) = 81, len(lon) = 480` and I need an array of `(81,480)`. I figure I would have to use an numpy where function to determine where the coordinate pairs match.

```
lat_alg = [-47.25 -47.25 -47.25 -48.   -48.   -48.   -48.   -48.   -48.   -48.
 -48.   -48.75 -48.75 -48.75 -48.75 -48.75 -48.75 -49.5  -49.5  -49.5
 -49.5  -50.25 -50.25 -50.25]
lon_alg = [225.75 226.5  227.25 226.5  227.25 228.   228.75 229.5  230.25 231.
 231.75 228.   228.75 229.5  230.25 231.   231.75 229.5  230.25 231.
 231.75 230.25 231.   231.75]
```

The boolean array I create is ...
`ar_tracker = np.zeros((len(lat),len(lon)))`

and I want the output to be 1 where the coordinates match.

Comment: Please indicate wether one of the answers is suitable for you !  If one of it is the accepted answer for you then you might click the "accepted" check box (which is just below the up/down vote signs and gets green when clicked). So everybody knows, that no more answers are needed and that this task is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have real values you cannot check with `==`. So we have to use windows confined by inequalities. As a result we get the indices of the elements within the choosen window (*11 and 12 in this example*)

```
# 1. build numpy arrays
lat = np.array([-47.25, -47.25, -47.25, -48.,   -48.,   -48.,   -48.,   -48.,   -48.,   -48., -48.,   -48.75, -48.75, -48.75, -48.75, -48.75, -48.75, -49.5,  -49.5,  -49.5, -49.5,  -50.25, -50.25, -50.25])
lon= np.array([225.75, 226.5,  227.25, 226.5,  227.25, 228.,   228.75, 229.5,  230.25, 231., 231.75, 228.,   228.75, 229.5,  230.25, 231.,   231.75, 229.5,  230.25, 231., 231.75, 230.25, 231., 231.75])


# 2. pick the values in the desired window for each data series, set to zeros the others
La = np.where( (lat> -49.0) & (lat<-48), lat, 0*lat)
Lo = np.where( (lon>226) & (lon<229), lon, 0*lon)

#3. give the indices where both series are non-zero
ind = np.argwhere(np.abs(Lo*La)>0.0001)
ind
array([[11],
       [12]], dtype=int64)
```

Or If you prefere an array with booleans:

```
(np.abs(Lo*La)>0.0001).astype(int)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```python
import numpy as np

lat_alg = np.array([-47.25, -47.25, -47.25, -48., -48., -48., -48., -48., -48.,
                    -48., -48., -48.75, -48.75, -48.75, -48.75, -48.75, -48.75,
                    -49.5, -49.5, -49.5, -49.5, -50.25, -50.25, -50.25])
lon_alg = np.array([225.75, 226.5, 227.25, 226.5, 227.25, 228., 228.75, 229.5,
                    230.25, 231., 231.75, 228., 228.75, 229.5, 230.25, 231.,
                    231.75, 229.5, 230.25, 231., 231.75, 230.25, 231., 231.75])

desired_position = np.array([-47.5, 228])
tolerance = 1

lat = np.abs(lat_alg - desired_position[0]) <= tolerance
lon = np.abs(lon_alg - desired_position[1]) <= tolerance 

desired_area = np.outer(lat, lon).astype(int)
```

If you want to compare exact matches instead of coordinate *windows*, try using [numpy.isclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html?highlight=isclose#numpy.isclose) to avoid float-point discrepancies:

```python
import numpy as np

lat_alg = np.array([-47.25, -47.25, -47.25, -48., -48., -48., -48., -48., -48.,
                    -48., -48., -48.75, -48.75, -48.75, -48.75, -48.75, -48.75,
                    -49.5, -49.5, -49.5, -49.5, -50.25, -50.25, -50.25])
lon_alg = np.array([225.75, 226.5, 227.25, 226.5, 227.25, 228., 228.75, 229.5,
                    230.25, 231., 231.75, 228., 228.75, 229.5, 230.25, 231.,
                    231.75, 229.5, 230.25, 231., 231.75, 230.25, 231., 231.75])

desired_position = np.array([-47.5, 228])

lat = np.isclose(lat_alg - desired_position[0], 0)
lon = np.isclose(lon_alg - desired_position[1], 0)

exact_matches = np.outer(lat, lon).astype(int)
```

Both `desired_area` and `exact_matches` are 2d arrays with shape `(len(lat), len(lon))`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be totally sure about if the pair exists, I suggest you build a list of tuples where each tuple contains a pair (lat,lon). For example:

```
def Mesh(X,Y):
    A=[]
    for x,y in zip(X,Y):
        A.append((x,y))

    return A

Coord=Mesh(lat_alg,lon_alg)
```

Then, if you know your grid resolution, you can easily check a pair as follows:

```
coord=(-49.5,230.25)

if coord in Coord:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```