# R: Populate rectangular grid with coordinate pair

Tags: python, r

Given a list of xy coordinates how can one populate a rectangular xy grid with standard incremental changes of 0.5 with where a given coordinate pair occurs?

For example, say we have the following coordinate pairs:

```
pts <- data.frame(X = c(1.9,2.4,1.1), Y = c(4.5,1.2,3.2))
```

And empty grid such as:

```
gridX = seq(0,2.5,by=0.5)
gridY = seq(0,5,by=0.5)
```

How to create a result which indicates whether a grid section contains
a coordinate pair such that:

```
    result
      0 0.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 4.5 5
1 0.0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0
2 0.5 0   0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0
3 1.0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0
4 1.5 0   0 0   0 0   0 0   1 0   1 0
5 2.0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0
6 2.5 0   0 0   1 0   0 0   0 0   0 0
```

A somewhat similar question is posed here (using Python): [How to check if a coordinate pair (lat,lon) exists in a coordinate grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57294654/how-to-check-if-a-coordinate-pair-lat-lon-exists-in-a-coordinate-grid). However I need to figure out how to this for multiple coordinate pairs, including instances where more than one coordinate pair might fall within the same grid section, that grid section would still be 1.

Comment: Why are your points in the grid `(1.9, 4.5) -> [1.5, 4.5]; (2.4, 1.2) -> [2.5, 1.5]; (1.1, 3.2) -> [1.5, 3.5]`? I would have expected `[1.5, 4.5]; [2.0, 1.0]; [1.0, 3.0]`?

Comment: @MartinGal yes you are correct with how the sets of coordinates should be matched to each grid, using the round function achieves this. So then based on your answer, I would simply round all of my coordinate pairs to nearest 0.5 and then match to the row and column headers per coordinate pair?

Comment: See my updated answer. Perhaps that solves your issue.

Comment: @Avril I think that your `result` table may be wrong. In my view, `gridX` should be for the **columns**, and `gridY` should be for the **rows**. Also, please see me updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build upon the following.

```r
pts <- data.frame(X = c(1.9,2.4,1.1), Y = c(4.5,1.2,3.2))

gridX = seq(0, 2.5, by=0.5)
gridY = seq(0, 5, by=0.5)

grid.matrix <- matrix(0, nrow=length(gridY), ncol=length(gridX))

grid <- data.frame(
  grid.matrix,
  row.names=gridY)

colnames(grid) <- gridX
```

The only thing left now is to find the correct row and column. This can be done with an `iflese`, for example.

**EDIT**

A better way to do it is to use `match` and `aggregate`. The full code listening looks as follows.

```r
pts <- data.frame(X = c(1.9,2.4,1.1), Y = c(4.5,1.2,3.2))

gridX = seq(0, 2.5, by=0.5)
gridY = seq(0, 5, by=0.5)

grid.matrix <- matrix(0, nrow=length(gridY), ncol=length(gridX))

grid <- data.frame(
  grid.matrix,
  row.names=gridY)

colnames(grid) <- gridX

pts$X.in.grid <- round(pts$X*2)/2
pts$Y.in.grid <- round(pts$Y*2)/2

pts$X.idx.in.grid <- match( pts$X.in.grid , colnames(grid) )
pts$Y.idx.in.grid <- match( pts$Y.in.grid , row.names(grid))

df.update <- aggregate(
  X.idx.in.grid + Y.idx.in.grid ~ X.idx.in.grid + Y.idx.in.grid ,
  pts, length )
colnames(df.update)[3] <- "value"

for (index in 1:nrow(df.update)) {
  grid[ df.update$Y.idx.in.grid[index], df.update$X.idx.in.grid[index] ] <- df.update$value[index]
}
```

which gives you.

```r
structure(list(`0` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `0.5` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `1.5` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `2.5` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("0", "0.5", "1", "1.5", "2", "2.5", 
"3", "3.5", "4", "4.5", "5"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am still somewhat unclear what you mean by the iflese function. For example, once I have grid dataframe setup as per your suggestion, how do I correctly identify the matrix positions where the column and row intersect at the location where each of the pts are?

Comment: I updated and edited my answer. Please have a look. If it does what you want, please consider to mark it as the correct answer AND give it an upvote. Thank you!

Comment: the first line of the updated part throws the following error: `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Y.idx.in.grid, value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 3`

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to include some code lines. Please check again!

Answer (score 1):

Since your grid uses a step width of `0.5` you could use

```r
> floor(pts*2)/2
    X   Y
1 1.5 4.5
2 2.0 1.0
3 1.0 3.0
```

to get the points on your grid.

Depending on your rounding logic, you could replace `floor` by

```r
> ceiling(pts*2)/2
    X   Y
1 2.0 4.5
2 2.5 1.5
3 1.5 3.5
```

or simply by rounding

```r
> round(pts*2)/2
    X   Y
1 2.0 4.5
2 2.5 1.0
3 1.0 3.0
```

#### Adding the points to your grid

Adding the points to your grid depends on the data structure your grid is stored in.

For example: Your grid is stored in a matrix with named rows and columns

```r
grid <- matrix(0, ncol=length(gridX), nrow=length(gridY))
rownames(grid) <- gridX
colnames(grid) <- gridY
```

and your new points are given by

```r
new_pts <- round(pts*2)/2
```

In this case retrieve your desired matrix by

```r
grid[as.character(new_pts$X), as.character(new_pts$Y)] <- diag(1,nrow(new_pts))
```

That's not very sophisticated, but it works.